# How to correctly use Contains on a java List holding HashMaps

Tags: java

How can I use `contains` method on a list that contains `HashMaps` so that it returns true when I ask whether or not the list contains a specified `HashMap`

For Example:

```
    List ssibenefit = new ArrayList();
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put("one", "1");
    ssibenefit.add(map);
    HashMap map4 = new HashMap();
    map4.put("one", "1");

    System.out.println("size: " + ssibenefit.size());
    System.out.println("does it contain orig: " + ssibenefit.contains(map));
    System.out.println("does it contain new: " + ssibenefit.contains(new HashMap().put("one", "1")));
```

should return:

```
size: 1
does it contain orig: true
does it contain new: true
```

but in this case the actual output is

```
size: 1
does it contain orig: true
does it contain new: false
```

**Update**

Sorry, I've updated the question. As I was posting the question, I realized what I wanted to do and what I was asking were not the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid the answers you've been given so far (prior to Vlad's answer) are all complete rubbish (which is surprising, because this is pretty basic stuff!).

The reason your test prints `false` where you would like to see `true` is that `put("one", "1")` returns the previous value of the mapping, not the map you've just manipulated. So, your call to `ssibenefit.contains` is asking if the list contains `null`. Which it doesn't.

On the other hand, if you rewrite your test:

```
HashMap newMap = new HashMap();
newMap.put("one", "1");
System.out.println("does it contain new: " + ssibenefit.contains(newMap));
```

You will see that it prints true.

If you read the javadoc for [List.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29), you'll see that it

> returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))

So, it works by equality, not identity, as others have asserted. And if you read the javadoc for [Map.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), you'll see that it

> Returns true if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the same mappings

So, equality is defined as equality of content, not identity. Putting those two together, you can see that what you're trying to do must work on any compliant implementation of Java.

Comment: ahhh so there is no need to implement `comparable`

Comment: Great! thanks for the post. Is there a way to also find out the specified position where it found the element? If I can get that then I can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int) to fetch the element.

Comment: Indeed.  I've deleted my erroneous answer.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

The [`put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) method in `HashMap` returns the previous value associated with the key, it doesn't return the `HashMap` itself. It's not a compile error because `contains` takes an `Object` as its argument.

That aside, [`List.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) uses `equals` for comparisons, and [`AbstractMap.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), inherited by `HashMap`,  tests for the two maps having the same mappings, not being the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

It returns true for the added maps because you are passing the same instances that exist in the list. If you want to be able to check for maps that are not the exact same instance you would need Comparable on the Maps.